# Return the value as Blender does when in the Python Console

Tags: python, scripting

I hate to post this question as I am sure it is something simple but well over my head. I have tried an exhaustive search but I think I am missing the correct key words.

Example of my issue in the Blender Python Console

Enter this into the console;

```
x = bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree
```

Type x and returns the following

```
bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree
```

Now type `print(x)` and return

```
<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree("Shader Nodetree") at 0x000001CB54D52008>
```

How can I make the print(x) code return

```
bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree
```

?

Comment: I think this may be a difference between the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods of objects:
`>>> x.__repr__()` gives
`"bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree"`
And `>>> x.__str__()` gives `'<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree("Shader Nodetree")>`

Comment: A little research on what you posted here and now I feel better about python methods in general.  A little eye opener for me, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Representation**

The python console echos the representation of a python object.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> repr(C.object)
"bpy.data.objects['Cube']"
```

For same output in either

```
>>> print(repr(C.object))
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

which uses this method defined on the class

```
>>> C.object.__repr__()
"bpy.data.objects['Cube']"
```

The output of a print method, is object as a string  `str(C.object)` is the result of   `C.object.__str__(self)`

```
>>> str(C.object)
'<bpy_struct, Object("Cube") at 0x7fb61a34a608>'

>>> print(C.object)
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube") at 0x7fb61a34a608>
```

Comment: Thank you once again for the help. I am obviously missing some critical learning when it comes to python and any of the methods with double underscores. I will study up on what you and @NeverConvex have shared

Comment: Unless you are defining the class, simply use `repr(ob)`  Underscored properties don't autocomplete &  NP with Q Happy to see you using the console.   Welcome to BSE.